# How to get the layout count present in slide master with office js

Tags: office-js, javascript-api-for-office

I want to access layout count which are present in slide master.

```
const slideMaster = context.presentation.slideMasters.getItem(0).layouts;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [PowerPoint.SlideMasterCollection class](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/powerpoint/powerpoint.slidemastercollection?view=powerpoint-js-preview) offers the `items` property which you can use the count the number of layouts in the SlideMasterCollection. The [Add slides to a presentation](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-snippets/blob/main/samples/powerpoint/slide-management/add-slides.yaml) snippet shows some strategies for working with layouts.